# routes between components in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi I have react component like this with routes. When i go to `localhost:8000` it loads the A component correctly but when i try `localhost:8080/broute` then its not working.
How can i make it working?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute, hashHistory     } from 'react-router'
import A from './components/A.jsx'
import B from './components/B.jsx'

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history = {browserHistory}>
    <Route path = "/" component = {A}>
      <IndexRoute component = {A}/>
      <Route path = "broute" component = {B} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: it's not working, so what is the problem did you see in your browser?

Comment: cannot get /broute

Comment: Do you use webpack dev server?

Comment: it shows valid. I tried to put wrong link also and noticed for wrong link i get [react-router] Location "/test" did not match any routes and for /broute it does not show this error but does not update the html. shows default / html

Comment: what does your index.html look like?